# Cleaning Up a Program that Continuously Builds a String out of Webpage

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm looking to either clean up or make more efficient my program, but I'm not sure how. Here's what my program does:

I take a webpage, turn it into a string, scan it for a keyword, if I don't find the keyword, I rebuild the string taking care of any possible page edits (effectively refreshing the webpage), and this program goes on forever. If ever the webpage is not available, it just runs the main program again. It's a monitoring program.

I can imagine this constant string building to consume memory over time, similar to a memory leak. Anyway to fix this cleverly?

Also, can I print a message to the windows command prompt in a java program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your code releases references to the objects that it holds, then the garbage collector will free up the memory for you. You don't have to do anything else.

To print to the console, its as simple as this.

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

or

```
System.out.printf("Hello %s%n", "World");
```

Comment: That's what I Thought, but when I compile my program as a .jar and run it, it doesn't print any message. Basically I just want a palpable way of showing that the program is indeed running once I execute the .jar.

Comment: Try a simple hello world using your method. If that works, then there's something wrong with the program. If that doesn't work then there's something wrong with the build method.

Comment: So I made a new project that says "Hello, world!" It compiles and runs in netbeans. I then use netbeans functionality to build a jar (run, clean and build main project). In the dist folder of my project there's a jar file. When I run it, it still does not print to the windows console, so the build is wrong. How should I be building my jar?

Comment: Go find the jar and double click it.

Comment: Try opening a command prompt, cd to the dist directory and run it like this: `java -jar my.jar` (where my.jar is the appropriate jar file name).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just being a little silly, sorry! Now I just got to find out how to turn this into a file that people who don't understand how to use command prompt, can run. Like an executable!